# Redistribution command

Tags: bgp

Consider the following config:

```
router bgp 2
 address-family ipv4 vrf TEST_VRF     
  redistribute static metric 10
 exit-address-family
Router#
```

Q1:The above command snippet does the following:

1.I am telling BGP to run inside my vrf TEST_VRF

2.I am redistributing all the static routes **present in TEST_VRF  routing table** into bgp with a metric of 10

Please confirm if my above understanding is correct.

Comment: You have not created any neighbors for your VRF address family.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You're not actually telling BGP to run inside VRF. I would say you're activating address family ipv4 vrf inside BGP process. I. e. BGP process is always bgp 2, but it may contain different address families.
2. Correct.